# Linear Combination of Vectors simple problem

Tags: linear-algebra

So I've embarked on teaching myself Linear Algebra with G. Hadley's book which I found in my mom's library. The first chapter teacher vectors, linear dependence, and define subspaces and bases but I can't solve this simple problem in the problems section:

Express x=[4,5] as a linear combination of a=[1,3], b=[2,2].

So by my understanding this is asking what scalars can you multiply these vectors by and then add them so you get [4,5] as a solution. But it seems to me logically that no matter how you manipulate these values you can't get the difference between them to be only 1, since [1,3] has a difference of 2 and [2,2] just scales both values up equally. I'm sure I'm missing something simple and fundamental. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can also scale by non-integers.

Comment: Try to solve $c_1\Bbb a+c_2\Bbb b = \Bbb x$.

Comment: First solve the first component, that is find $x,y$ so that $1x+2y = 4$. This has many solutions, $x = 4-2y$. Now solve for the second component, using **the same** $x,y$ to get $2x+2y = 5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the linear system

$$\begin{cases}x\;\,+2y=4\\3x+2y=5\end{cases}$$

and you'll find the coefficients $\;x,y\;$ that give you the linear combination. As observed in the comments, these coefficients do **not** have to be integers, and also check the above system has a unique solution (why?)

Comment: oh ok, I knew it was something fundamental. I was thinking of the definition of linear dependence. Thank you.